# Dropwizard Client Certificate Authentication via HttpClient Key/Trust store

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, dropwizard

I am running a dropwizard server, and a client leveraging Apache HttpClient 4.5.1.

Given a single .pfx file that contains both the public and private keys, how would I structure my key/trust stores on both the server and client to accept/trust *and pass* the certificate for authentication purposes?

What I'm running into is the client trusts the provided server certificate, but
after the server hello that includes the certificate request per tls spec, my client is unable to find a suitable certificate to send back.

My first thought was to run the server with the keystore and truststore as the same pfx file, but java throws a null cert chain error when loading the pfx file as a trust store in the server.   So I had to go through the process of creating a trust store manually.

Here are the general steps I thought would allow this entire process to succeed:

1. Run the server with the .pfx file, with a PKCS12 keystore type.
2. Extract the cert from the pfx file, and create a java trust store using the cert.
3. Run the server with the above clientCerts.jks file as the trust store
4. Run the client with a keystore set to the clientCerts.jks file
5. Run the client with a truststore set to the .pfx PKCS12 keystore.

These steps didn't work, and I've tried other less obvious permutations and none of them worked.  Is there something blatantly wrong with the way I'm approaching this?  Does anyone have any advice on actually getting it to work?

Lots of details below (including ssl debug logs)

PFX cert info: 
(its a valid corporate signed cert, but I don't have the root CA as trusted anywhere, which is why I just create a trust store so I can trust the client cert).

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -in cert.pfx
Enter Import Password:
MAC Iteration 1
MAC verified OK
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2000
Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00
    friendlyName: xxx
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
xxx
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2000
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00
    friendlyName: my.domain.com
subject=/C=US/O=My Company/OU=Web Servers/CN=my.domain.com
issuer=/C=US/O=My Company
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Java Trust store Creation:

```
//create pem file
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out tempCert.crt -nokeys -clcerts

//convert to x509
openssl x509 -inform pem -in tempCert.crt -outform der -out tempx509Cert.cer

//create a java trust store
keytool -import -file tempx509Cert.cer -alias firstCA -keystore newJavaTrustStore.jks
```

Dropwizard Config:

```
applicationConnectors:
    - type: https
      port: 443
      bindHost: localhost 
      keyStorePath: ./cert.pfx
      keyStorePassword: pw
      keyStoreType: PKCS12
      trustStorePath: ./clientCerts.jks
      trustStorePassword: pw
      trustStoreType: JKS
      supportedProtocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
      excludedProtocols: [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3]
      validateCerts: false
      needClientAuth: true
      wantClientAuth: true
```

HttpClient Config Values:

```
keyStorePath: ./clientCerts.jks
keyStorePassword: pw
keyStoreType: JKS   
trustStorePath: ./cert.pfx
trustStorePassword: pw
trustStoreType: PKCS12
```

HttpClient Config:

```
public static CloseableHttpClient getSecurePooledHttpClient(
        final String host,
        final int port,
        final boolean ssl,
        final String keystorePath,
        final String keystorePassword,
        final String keystoreType,
        final String trustStorePath,
        final String trustStorePassword,
        final String trustStoreType



) throws Exception {

    //Setup the keystore that will hold the client certificate
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(keystorePath)),
            keystorePassword.toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

    //Setup the Trust Store so we know what certificates 
    //we can trust that are hosting the service
    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance((trustStoreType));
    ts.load(new FileInputStream(new File(trustStorePath)), 
            trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    tmf.init(ts);


    //setup our SSL context to be TLSv1.2, then setup the key and trust manager.
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);



    //Register the socket factory so that it uses the ssl Context and key
    // manager we created above
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = 
            RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("https", new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, 
                    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
            .build();

    //Define an overridden routeplanner that setups up our default host 
    // so all our later calls can simply be
    //sub-routes.
    HttpRoutePlanner routePlanner = 
            new DefaultRoutePlanner(DefaultSchemePortResolver.INSTANCE)
    {
        @Override
        public HttpRoute determineRoute(
                final HttpHost target,
                final HttpRequest request,
                final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
            return super.determineRoute(
                    target != null ? target : new HttpHost(host, port, ssl ? "https" : "http"),
                    request, context);
        }
    };
    return BuildClientWithRoutePlanner(socketFactoryRegistry, routePlanner);
```

Client SSL debug:

...

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-7, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=my.domain.com, OU=Web Servers, O=My Company, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
```

.........

```
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=my.domain.com, OU=Web Servers, O=My Company, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
```

......

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=my.domain.com, OU=Web Servers, O=My Company, C=US>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

Comment: did you figure out the issue?

Comment: Making a guess. I assume the same .pfx file is meant to be used at both the server and client side -the same public key is used by the client and server to encrypt and the same private key is used by both to decrypt.But I'm not so sure if this is possible as any certificate is meant for a particular Hostname and/or DNS (CN and SAN)and the Server and the Client may be in different hosts and/or DNS (and so the .pfx may not be applicable to both).

Comment: The issue I think is keyStore should contain both certificate (public key) + private key and trustStore should contain only the certificate(public key) ( in the case of your "client app" the trustStore should contain - either the server's certificate ( server's public key + others ) itself which signed by the CA or CA's certificate ( CA's public key + others ) ). Please let me know if my understanding was correct and if that was the issue ?